# In Mount and Blade Warband, I want to stop being Swadian rebels

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I tried to help out Lady Isolla of Suno when I had Dhirim and three or four castles. It didn't go well as in addition to the Swadians every other kingdom declared war on  me. I thought if I told Isolla I didn't support her anymore than I could stop being a part of Swadian rebels, but I still was being attacked by everyone.

So I emptied out my remaining two castles of their garrisons and let them be captured, but I'm still Swadian rebels even though some screens don't list the rebels as a kingdom anymore.

Will I ever be able to go back to just being a freelancer and not being chased attacked by everyone?

Comment: try and find a king you are on friendly terms with and see if he's willing to let you become his vassal?

Comment: I tried talking to the Swadian king, but he just wanted to fight me. And everyone is at war with me. At this point, I'd be willing to use a cheat or something to get rid of the Swadian rebels faction entirely, because I'm being chased by huge armies all over the map.

Comment: hmm.. I'd try talking to one while they are in town so you have the option to discuss things rather than meeting them in the field when you can only attack or retreat

Comment: Thanks that helped. I was able to pay for peace with the nords, build up an army, and taKe a castle, and once I had land of my own the Nord king was willing to let me be a vassal.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by paying one of the Nord vassals to make peace with them. Now I should be able to find the Nord king and become his vassal, and end the issue. Luckily, I had just barely enough to pay the 25k they wanted.